# python script stuck on reading from stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason a script that always worked is now failing :(
I investigated and trimmed down to something minimal, still not working:

cat a.py:

```
import sys

for row in sys.stdin.readlines():
  print("hey")
  print(row)
```

Testing:

```
>> cat b.csv
a,b,c
1,2,3

>> cat b.csv | python a.py
// hangs for ever, if I Ctrl+C:
for row in sys.stdin.readlines():
  KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any idea what could be going on? Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code runs fine when I try it.

Comment: thanks for trying. I have a mac that is kind of managed by our company, maybe an update screwed things up

Comment: If I run `sys.stdin.readlines()` by itself in the shell it will hang. Maybe `stdin` isn't receiving any bytes?

Comment: Could it be something where the file you are reading doesn't have an EOF marker?

Comment: I don't know think so, it should at least print the first rows and the first cat command successfully ends

Comment: Are these the *exact* contents of `b.csv` and the *exact* command you ran?

Comment: yes to all @user2357112

Comment: @SPYBUG96: Barring some sort of filesystem corruption, that's not how files work.

Comment: so I tried on python3 and 2, and it works as is on 2

Comment: asked a colleague, I guess something is screwed up on my computer. Installed latest python 3.7 and didn't work, not sure what's up :(

Comment: What happens if you type `Control-d` while it's hanging? This shouldn't work, but give it a try anyway.

Comment: CtrlD closes things cleanly and doesn't print anything

Comment: @user2357112 (and others) thanks for your help, see answer below :(

Comment: Side-note: You shouldn't use `.readlines()` here; doing that means that if `stdin` comes in piecemeal, you still have to wait for it to finish *completely* (and be closed) before you begin doing *any* work. Just looping over `for row in sys.stdin:` would process line by line as before, but it could begin processing as soon as there was a complete line available on `stdin`. Even if the input source buffers its output, beginning processing after a few KB of data is available, rather than after *all* the data is available, will be faster, more responsive, and more memory friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation, it looks like it has to do with the aliases I use.

[image: see commands]

Because I have different libraries for python2 and 3 I had

```
pythonpath2=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
pythonpath3=~/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
alias p="unset PYTHONPATH; export PYTHONPATH=${pythonpath3}; python3.7"
alias p2="unset PYTHONPATH; export PYTHONPATH=${pythonpath2}; echo $PYTHONPATH; python"
```

So I guess before piping in the terminal would pipe into the last command of the alias and a change made it pipe into the first command of the alias (unset) which made it ineffective

Comment: You should probably be using something like `virtualenv` instead of trying to implement virtual environments yourself. Also, another reason to use functions instead of aliases: every command in the function would inherit standard input from the function, whereas with the alias only `unset` would be connected to the pipe.

Comment: And another reason to show the *actual* code you are running in your post; someone would have immediately asked what `p` or `p2` was.

Comment: indeed, it's usually what we take for granted that fails :)

Comment: I will move this into a function then, didn't know that input behaved this way